# check if span element exists and then add div dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I check if a span exists below my input element and if it exists, I need to add a div dynamically below that span

```
$('#submit_form .required_text').filter(':visible').each(function () {
var input = $(this);
input.next('div.error_text').remove();
input.removeClass('highlight');
if (!$(this).val()) {
    input.addClass('highlight');
    input.find('span'){
        //then add the div after the span for this element alone
    }
    else{

        input.after('<div class="error_text">Required field</div>');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DRY out the code by placing the markup in a var and selecting the correct element into another var.  Use `.next()` to select the element after the input.  Then evaluate the nextElement to determine if it is a span.

```
var input = $("input"), nextElement = input.next();
var divHtml = '<div class="error_text">Required field</div>';
var elem = ($(nextElement).is("span")) ? nextElement: input;
$(elem).after(divHtml);
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Ha4CS/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(input.find('span').length)
  {
        // here do your stuff
    }
    else{// not exist 

        input.after('<div class="error_text">Required field</div>');
    }
```

Comment: Once again find is going to search for children of `input` which will not exist.